# My facebook app doesn't work, when user tries use http instead of https, why?

Tags: facebook, https, facebook-apps

In case when user do not have enabled "use https connection when it is possible" (in https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security) my app is not loading. How to fix that?

print screen with settings:

[image]

Comment: post some link, maybe a bit of the facebook application properties

have you configured your application with both http and https urls?

Comment: This is about this app https://www.facebook.com/eKundelek/app_450517974974351

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Page Tab URL and Canvas URL to a HTTP URL, and the Secure Page Tab URL and Secure Canvas URL to a HTTPS URL.

You can't use HTTP or HTTPS for both, and if you omit any of them, users with that protocol won't be able to access your app

Comment: so, as you can see... settings should be ok.

Comment: You seem to have some sort of redirect in place on that page tab which loops infinitely, check your code